# PHP + MYSQL create table

Tags: php, mysql

SO, I want to create a pretty big mysql table that should save all of the squares of a chess board and their value, I'm using a PHP for() since it has 64 squares.
This always gives me 'not working'

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','pierostesting','');
mysql_select_db('my_pierostesting');
$query="CREATE TABLE board (";
for($i=0;$i<63;$i++){
    $query .= "i".$i." INT(1) NOT NULL,";
}
$query .="turno BOOL";
if (mysql_query($query)){
    echo 'working';
}else echo 'not working'; ?>
```

Comment: have a look at what `echo $query;` outputs, the problem should be obvious (look at the end of the string).  But **please** do **not** use the php 'mysql' extension for new code anymore, use either mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I litterally just noticed, haven't used php in so long that I've lost all fluency with it.

Comment: well yes these things happen :)  Voting to close as due to a typographical error now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot, didn't close the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

try echoing out your complete SQL string, then use phpMyAdmin and see if the sql string actually works, or if it throws errors. You may have a sql syntax error.

If it does work, make sure your connection variables are correct (host, db name, username, password)

that should get you close to the answer.